# Angular routing for newbie

Tags: angularjs, routes, single-page-application, angular-routing

I've just started learning angular & creating the first app. Help me please with routing.

**Folder Structure**

spa/
  index.html
  controllers/
    controllers.js
  images/
  javascript/
    app.js
  resources/
    angular-route.js
    angular.js
  views/
    cars.html
    home.html
    login.html
    profile.html

The pages from "/views" are not displayed.
Here's my code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>5 Angular</title>
    <script src="resources/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/app.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <nav>
      <ul class="navbar">
        <li>
          <a href = "#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href = "#Login">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href = "#profile">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href = "#cars">Cars</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**cars.html**

```
<h1>Cars Page</h1>
```

**home.html**

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>
```

**login.html**

```
<h1>Login Page</h1>
```

**profile.html**

```
<h1>Profile Page</h1>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
})
.when('login', {
templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
})
.when('cars', {
templateUrl: 'views/cars.html'
})
.when('profile', {
templateUrl: 'views/profile.html'
})
otherwise('/');
});
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.controller("mainCtrl",function($scope){

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create app module in `app.js` like `angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])`
You shouldn't recreate the app module in `controller.js` again which will flush all the initial registered component like here you did `.config` block for router settings.

It should be

```
angular.module('app')
```

instead of

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
```

Additionally `login` anchor should be `#/login` instead of `#Login` because `$routerProvider` has condition on `login`.
Also notice there should be a slash after the hash in the href.

```
<a href = "#/login">Login</a>
```

Comment: Pankaj, i've changed code according to your answer. I see e.g. "index.html#login" in the end of my address bar. But how can I get the content of my views to index.html?

Comment: @АнтонШомин, notice the answer is updated, try #/login

Comment: <ul class="navbar">
        <li>
          <a href = "#/home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href = "#/login">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href = "#/profile">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href = "#/cars">Cars</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

Still do not get content of views

Comment: And i have the most newbiest question. Should i have a server configured to do that? My application will read & write data from JSON located in the application folder

Comment: Yes..you need to setup a server and on that host all your code..which will also have `.json` file so that you can get access to it using `http` protocol

Comment: @wrath1888 I know it's been some time but I revisited this question and found some more issues. I recreated your setup and made sure everything works. The answer has been updated. Better late than never I guess.

Comment: @wrath1888 My edit has been rejected, in short, load angular.js first, then angular-route.js, then app.js, then controller.js. + in your routing you also have to prefix with '/', ex: .when('/profile', ...)